# Dapper materializing to a Tuple

Tags: c#, tuples, dapper, c#-7.0

I need return a list from dapper with the new tuple in C# 7.

```
public static List<(int StyleId, decimal StyleCode)> GetOnlyServices()
{
    var query = $@" SELECT
                    ST.style_id as StyleId, ST.style_code as StyleCode
                    ...
                    ...";

    using (SqlConnection db = new SqlConnection(InfobaseConString))
    {
        var a = db.Query<(int StyleId, decimal StyleCode)>(query, commandTimeout: 90).ToList();
        return a;
    }
}
```

But this function only return me 56 rows with `(0,0), Item1=0, Item2=0`.
What I missing?

Comment: What results were you expecting?

Comment: values... i get only 0,0 in all 56 rows... I expect values... The query is correct. If I change var a = db.Query(query, commandTimeout: 90); I get correct data [2] = {{DapperRow, StyleId = '534', StyleCode = '10000005'}}

Comment: Since that's the case, it wouldn't surprise me if Dapper doesn't support this feature yet.  You may have better luck posting an issue on the [project's site](https://github.com/StackExchange/dapper-dot-net).

Comment: I'd be very surprised if Dapper already supported C#7 features. I know Marc and Nick are on the ball, but I doubt they're worrying about this right now.

Comment: maybe try db.Query<Tuple<int, decimal>>(query, commandTimeout: 90)

Comment: or have a look at [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/34883374/215553), maybe you can use that `Query` signature with the `Tuple.Create` parameter

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Support has been added in version 1.50.4. You should be able to access the fields using their friendlier names now.

---

Original Answer:

Frankly, it's just not supported the way the tuples work.  Dapper's deserializer maps column values with constructor parameters or properties/fields by name in the object's type.  ([Source](https://github.com/DapperLib/Dapper/blob/23e6b64c9ff0121ce1c9a9dcf80648be20780d5c/Dapper/SqlMapper.cs#L2884) if you can understand the generated IL).

ValueTuples on the other hand still only have property names corresponding to items in the tuple (`Item1`, `Item2`, etc.) but uses compiler/ide magic to make them accessible by other names.  So `StyleId` or `StyleCode` will not be actual property names, they're just aliases for `Item1` and `Item2` respectively.

You'll either have to wait for the team to add in explicit support for ValueTuples or use the expected property names in your query.

```
var query = $@" SELECT
                ST.style_id as Item1, ST.style_code as Item2
                ...
                ...";
```

Answer (score 15):

Looks like they added this a few months ago. Here's an example usage from the [tests](https://github.com/StackExchange/Dapper/blob/master/Dapper.Tests/TupleTests.cs):

```cs
    [Fact]
    public void TupleReturnValue_Works_NamesIgnored()
    {
        var val = connection.QuerySingle<(int id, string name)>("select 42 as [Item2], 'Fred' as [Item1]");
        Assert.Equal(42, val.id);
        Assert.Equal("Fred", val.name);
    }
```

Comment: It's disappointing that Dapper's tuple mapping is based on positions rather than names, but at least it's something.